# Bloomberg API /blp/refdata: stockinfo

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am using `blpapi 3.5.5.` windows python api. I am getting intraday tick data using `//blp/refdata`, following fields: `BEST_BID`, `BEST_ASK` and `TRADE`. Using Bloomberg terminal I found fields: `IN_AUCTION`, `AUCTION_TYPE` and `TRADE_STATUS`, but none of it works, returning `NotFoundException`.
Dou you know any field that is containing stock info (e.g. in auction/continiuos trading) available in  `//blp/refdata`?

Comment: Show us what you have done and the traceback you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After communicating with support, we finally found the answer. When sending request, `'conditionCodes'` need to be set as `True`, then depending on stock exchange codes mainly for auction will be send, such as `OA` as opening auction, `IA` intraday auction, etc. Meaning some of codes can be found in the terminal using `QR <GO>`

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are not available for all securities.

For example `IN_AUCTION` returns a value for `VOD LN Equity` but not for `IBM US Equity`. HELP HELP may be able to explain why.

So you need to add some logic and check for the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Intraday Tick fields are limited to the following fields:

TRADE
BID
ASK
BID_BEST
ASK_BEST
BID_YIELD
ASK_YIELD
MID_PRICE
AT_TRADE
BEST_BID
BEST_ASK
SETTLE

You can optionally include the following fields:
Action Codes
BicMic Codes
Broker Codes
Client Specific Fields
Condition Codes
Eq Ref Price
Exchange Codes
Indicator Codes
Non Plottable Events
Rps Codes
Spread Price
Trade Id
Trade Time
Upfront Price
Yield

As for IN_AUCTION, AUCTION_TYPE and TRADE_STATUS, you can pull them using a ReferenceDataRequest, or subscribe to IN_AUCTION_RT, RT_EXCH_TRADE_STATUS, respectively.